# How to make the output numbers match the factorial results

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, output, factorial

I got an assignment to make a program using loops. User inputs a number from 1-98, then the output is a factorial of that number. If the user enters a number other than the number above, then the user is asked to re-enter the appropriate number. Now when the user input is appropriate, the output that comes out does not match the factorial results.

[here's the picture of that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqBmD.png)

and this is the code

```
num = int(input("Input Number (1-98) : "))

    Factorial = 1
    for a in range(1,num+1):
        if 0 < num < 99:
            Factorial = Factorial*a
        else :
            print("input does not match, Repeat input (1-98)")
            num = int(input("Input Number (1-98) :"))
    
    print ("The factorial of", num, "is", Factorial)
```

can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, whether it be code, console output or error messages. Please do walk through your own program and attempt to debug it before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate the *input part* and the *compute part*

```
num = -1
while not (0 < num < 99):
    num = int(input("Input Number (1-98) :"))

Factorial = 1
for a in range(1, num + 1):
    Factorial = Factorial * a

print("The factorial of", num, "is", Factorial)
```

---

The reason was

- you input `99`
- the loop runs for all value, computing factorial until 98
- `else` says `"input does not match"`
- loop is over or not, but you keep the computed factorial in memory and starts from there

Comment: in line 1, why num is -1?

Comment: @MUHAMMADRAFI To force the loop to run once, and write `input` once in the code, not before the loop and inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

first set the value not to meet condition and then repeat asking until the input meets criteria:

```
num = 0
while num < 1 or num > 98:
    num = int(input("Input Number (1-98) : "))

factorial = 1
for a in range(1, num):
    factorial = factorial * (a+1)

print (f"The factorial of {num} is {factorial}")
```

then there is no need to multiply by 1 so we start at 1 and always multiply by a+1 (that gets rid of one iteration).
range(1..num) produces numbers from 1 to num -1. Therefore if we multiply by a+1 we effectively multiply with numbers in range 2 to num, which is what we want.

And at last a modern way of outputing strings